# How to import certificate into truststore in Adobe Experience Manager

Tags: certificate

The peer site that AEM is trying to visit has a self signed certificate.
The question is how to import the self signed certificate into the AEM truststore.

Adobe has an article about this at
https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/forms/using/admin-help/certificates.html

> In administration console, click Settings >Trust Store Management > Certificates.

However, I cannot find "Settings" in the admin console in AEM 6.3.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score -2):

The documentation is for Forms JEE. For AEM OSGI, you can follow the steps on https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/administering/using/saml-2-0-authenticationhandler.html#AddtheIdPCertificatetotheAEMTrustStore

SAML assertions are signed and may optionally be encrypted. In order for this to work you have to provide at least the public certificate of the IdP in the repository. In order to do this you need to:

- Go to:
  http://localhost:4502/libs/granite/security/content/useradmin.html
- Click on any of the users in the list.
- Go under Account Settings, and press the Create TrustStore link.
- Enter the password for the TrustStore and press Save.
- Click on Manage TrustStore.
- Upload the IdP certificate.
- Take note of the certificate Alias.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.